# Start up form couldnt close after loading vb

Tags: vb.net

I create form which get password in textbox then after the password enter correctly, the main form loads. so i use this method in password form :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If txtpass.Text = "sarina" Then
        MsgBox("Correct", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Pass Correct")
        Form1.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Incorrect", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Pass Incorrect")
    End If

End Sub
```

now after the password enter correctly, i want to close password form with this code :

```
startup.close()
```

i put this code into Load event in main form. but the problem is that when i debug program, after i enter correct password, both forms close. how can i do this ? i mean, after enter correct password the password form close and then main form loads. How ?

Answer (score 0):

you must hide the parent form and the close it after the child form is finished

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If txtpass.Text = "sarina" Then
        MsgBox("Correct", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Pass Correct")
        Me.Hide '<--| hide your currently open form
        Form1.Show() '<--| load and show new form
        Unload Form1  '<--| unload new form
    Else
        MsgBox("Incorrect", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Pass Incorrect")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option is that by default the Shutdown Mode of a new project is "When startup form closes". Since you closed the startup form, you shutdown the program. You can change that to "When **last** form closes".

You can find this on the menu bar under Project > Properties. Look near the bottom of the Application section.